# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 when trying to compile AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: xcode, linker, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, i386

I added AFNetworking 2.0 to my project.
I did it without the use CocoaPods - I just added the files to the project, making sure to copy the files to target.

When I try to compile the project I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFServerTrustIsValid in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in AFSecurityPolicy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is wrong with my project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your missing iOS frameworks in the project.
I bet security framework is one of them from the names I see.

Answer (score 5):

`#import <Security/Security.h>` in your PCH file + make sure the library is in "Link Binary With Libraries".

Answer (score 0):

Just add security.framework in your project.